# how to avoid jQuery UI draggable from also triggering click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

A have a large div (a map) that is draggable via jQuery UI draggable. The div has child divs which are clickable.

My problem is that if you drag the map, on mouse up, the click event is fired on whatever child div you started the drag from.

How do I stop the mouse up from triggering the click event if its part of a drag (as opposed to someone just clicking without a drag, in which case the click event is desired).

Comment: I had the same problem and have found a simple solution. On the child element define `draggable` before `click`, like this: `$('element').draggable({disabled: true});`

Answer (score 50):

```
$('.selector').draggable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        // event.toElement is the element that was responsible
        // for triggering this event. The handle, in case of a draggable.
        $( event.originalEvent.target ).one('click', function(e){ e.stopImmediatePropagation(); } );
    }
});
```

This works because *"one-listeners"* are fired **before** *"normal"* listeners. So if a one-listener stops propagation, it will never reach your previously set listeners.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qYz9V/2/ here is the fiddle of this answer :) thank you.

Comment: the fiddle shows it's working, but for some reason it doesn't for me...

Comment: This solution is not working in FF 31, event.toElement is undefined. However instead of event.toElement use event.originalEvent.target will work in all browsers

Comment: This doesn't work if the click event is attached to the child.

Comment: This prevents the next real click to the target. I have to double click for the click to work again.

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem and the solution is to apply the draggable event handler BEFORE the click event handler.  I was moving some code around and suddenly had this problem.  I finally realized I had switched the order in which I applied the handlers.  When I switched it back, things started working properly again -- drag did not cause a click.

Comment: Arghh, I've been trying to fix this problem, and wish your solution worked for me.  But it doesn't.  I'm on jQuery 1.6.1

Comment: Worked for me!  Much better than all the shnanigans-ey other answers.

Comment: none of which work for me :-(

Comment: Worked for me like charm, just be sure to set the draggable event before the click event like mentiened... thank you for the solution :D

Comment: Still true 7 years later! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Could you perhaps set a variable such as "justDragged = true" when starting the drag and then on the mouseUp event check this variable and if true, set it to false and then do a event.preventDefault + return w/o doing anything. This way it skips the first click after the drag. Seems kind of hackish, perhaps others will have a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to simply not allow dragging from clickable areas within the draggable:

[jQuery UI Draggable API](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#handle)

Comment: Care to explain the downvotes?