# Prevent click event after drag in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a draggable `<div>` with a `click` event and without any event for drag,
but after I drag `<div>` the click event is apply to `<div>`.

How can prevent of click event after drag?

```
$(function(){
    $('div').bind('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('orange');
    });

    $('div').draggable();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/prince4prodigy/aG72R/

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486760/how-to-avoid-jquery-ui-draggable-from-also-triggering-click-event

Comment: - notice the x and y postions of your div on load.
 - check if the div has beed moved
 - if yes,remove the style you have assigned

Comment: check out my solution (much easier than any in this thread) https://stackoverflow.com/a/58836706/5934567

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made a solution with `data` and `setTimeout`. Maybe better than helper classes.

```
<div id="dragbox"></div>
```

and

```
$(function(){
    $('#dragbox').bind('click', function(){
        if($(this).data('dragging')) return;
        $(this).toggleClass('orange');
    });

    $('#dragbox').draggable({
        start: function(event, ui){
            $(this).data('dragging', true);
        },
        stop: function(event, ui){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(event.target).data('dragging', false);
            }, 1);
        }
    });
});
```

Check the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MightyPork/aG72R/8/)**.

Answer (score 26):

FIRST attach the draggable event, THEN the click event:

```
$(function(){
    $('div').draggable();
    $('div').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('orange');
    });
});
```

Try it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/aG72R/55/

Comment: This is the best of the answers, imo.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution and this is how it's intended to work. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dAL5v

Answer (score 13):

## With an ES6 class (No jQuery)

To achieve this in javascript without the help of jQuery you can add and remove an event handler.

First create functions that will be added and removed form event listeners

```
flagged () {
    this.isScrolled = true;
}
```

and this to stop all events on an event

```
preventClick (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

Then add the flag when the `mousedown` and `mousemove` events are triggered one after the other.

```
element.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
    element.addEventListener('mousemove', flagged);
});
```

Remember to remove this on a mouse up so we don't get a huge stack of events repeated on this element.

```
element.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
    element.removeEventListener('mousemove', flagged);
});
```

Finally inside the `mouseup` event on our element we can use the flag logic to add and remove the click.

```
element.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
    if (this.isScrolled) {
        e.target.addEventListener('click', preventClick);
    } else {
        e.target.removeEventListener('click', preventClick);
    }
    this.isScrolled = false;
    element.removeEventListener('mousemove', flagged);
});
```

In the above example above I am targeting the real target that is clicked, so if this were a slider I would be targeting the image and not the main gallery `element`. to target the main `element` just change the add/remove event listeners like this.

```
element.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
    if (this.isScrolled) {
        element.addEventListener('click', preventClick);
    } else {
        element.removeEventListener('click', preventClick);
    }
    this.isScrolled = false;
    element.removeEventListener('mousemove', flagged);
});
```

## Conclusion

By setting anonymous functions to const we don't have to bind them. Also this way they kind of have a "handle" allowing s to remove the specific function from the event instead of the entire set of functions on the event.

Comment: from all the 10 links i've searched on stackoverflow, and all the hours of testing. this was the single solution that worked..because IM NOT using jquery as everyone else...thanks a lot man!

Comment: THANKS works great for me! I implemented it on my lightweight JS slider https://github.com/hrsetyono/hSlider

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$(function(){

    $('div').draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).addClass('noclick');
    }
});

$('div').click(function(event) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('noclick')) {
        $(this).removeClass('noclick');
    }
    else {
        $(this).toggleClass('orange');
    }
});
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Sy6KQ/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without jQuery UI draggable. Just using common 'click' and 'dragstart' events:

```
$('div').on('dragstart', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).data('dragging', true);
}).on('click', function (e) {
  if ($(this).data('dragging')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).data('dragging', false);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just check for jQuery UI's `ui-draggable-dragging` class on the draggable. If it's there, don't continue the click event, else, do. jQuery UI handles the setting and removal of this class, so you don't have to. :)

**Code:**

```
$(function(){
    $('div').bind('click', function(){
        if( $(this).hasClass('ui-draggable-dragging') ) { return false; }
        $(this).toggleClass('orange');
    });

    $('div').draggable();
});
```

Comment: i did not see that class

Answer (score 0):

## With React

This code is for React users, checked the draggedRef when mouse up.

I didn`t use click event. The click event checked by the mouse up event.

```js
const draggedRef = useRef(false);

...

<button
  type="button"
  onMouseDown={() => (draggedRef.current = false)}
  onMouseMove={() => (draggedRef.current = true)}
  onMouseUp={() => {
    if (draggedRef.current) return;

    setLayerOpened(!layerOpened);
  }}
>
  BTN
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (tho with p5.js) and I solved it by having a global `lastDraggedAt` variable, which was updated when the drag event ran. In the click event, I just checked if the last drag was less than 0.1 seconds ago.

```
function mouseDragged() {
    // other code
    lastDraggedAt = Date.now();
}

function mouseClicked() {
    if (Date.now() - lastDraggedAt < 100)
        return; // its just firing due to a drag so ignore
    // other code
}
```