# Avoid click event on a widget

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Hello i have this widgets that i have to avoid the click event when i going to move them using DND and my question is how i can avoid the default behavior?
My biggest problem is with the select widgets because shows the options and dissapear the widget. 
This is the code of the draggable element.

```
$(elmnt).draggable({
    cancel: null,
    scroll: true, 
    scrollSensitivity: 100,
    refreshPositions: true  });
```

BTW: I am using jQueryUI to make the draggable
Thanks!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771627/preventing-click-event-with-jquery-drag-and-drop

Comment: thanks!!! Solve my problem!!!!

Comment: Hey hidura - maybe you should select polarblau's answer as the answer - i.e. since the answer is a comment create an aswer question and set as solved otherwise the question just lingers in the unanswered que