# jQuery UI Sortable stop event after drag and drop

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am working with the jQuery UI Sortable plugin and everything works as expected accept for one issue. After I am done dragging an item to reorder the list (a list of `<A>` tags) the click event fires after the drop is done.

Anyone run into this issue before? If so, how did you go about fixing it?

Comment: Can you build test case reproducing your problem in [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: Are you sure it's the click event? There are a few other events that fire after a drop is done (the most common might be the "change" event). Might be able to supply a better answer if you show us your code.

Comment: Perhaps this will help as it seems like this is what you are running into: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1771635/37140

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/dennismonsewicz/5VgSq/

Comment: I am also working with iviewer which might be causing the issue... @ChrisMitchell - I tried your suggestion, but no luck :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok... I figured it out..

Here is my solution:

```
$(thumbOpts.container).sortable({
        items: '.page',
        revert: true,
        opacity: 0.5,
        start: function(evt, ui) {
            var link = ui.item.find('a');
            link.data('click-event', link.attr('onclick'));
            link.attr('onclick', '');
        },
        stop: function(evt, ui) {
            setTimeout(
                function(){
                    var link = ui.item.find('a');
                    link.attr('onclick', link.data('click-event'));
                },
                    200
            )
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ok +1, but don't you think a cleaner solutions should exist?

Comment: is there event when sorting is in progress? Something like draggable (when dragging)?

Answer (score 1):

Just add option for sortable:

```
helper : 'clone'
```

It will prevent click event for source element and don't change anyhow UX.

See [doc for "helper"](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-helper).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(thumbOpts.container).sortable({
        items: '.page',
        revert: true,
        opacity: 0.5,
        start: function(evt, ui) {
            ui.item.find('a').one('click', function(){return false;});
        },
});
```