# Prevent click event triggered when dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, onclick, draggable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preventing click event with jQuery drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771627/preventing-click-event-with-jquery-drag-and-drop)

Assuming there is a slider of photo gallery. User can drag on the photo slider and select the photo to view when click on the photo. The problem is the click event is overlap with drag event. That means, when user click on the photo to drag, it will occur the click event as well. Thanks

```
    //slider is draggable
    $('#slider').draggable({axis: "x"});

    //slider photo click event
    $('#slider li').click(function() {
        page_index = $(this).attr('class').substring(4);
        tmp = parseInt(page_index);
        $('#book').turn('page', tmp);
        close_overlay();
    })
```

Comment: sorry it seems the bug is caused by my pervious code, the link you provided working well. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this issue caused by event bubbling. Try my solution

```
function cancelBubbleEvent(e) {
    if (e) {
         e.stopPropagation();
    }
    else {
         window.event.cancelBubble = true;
    }
}

//slider is draggable
$('#slider').draggable({axis: "x"});

//slider photo click event
$('#slider li').click(function(e) {
    page_index = $(this).attr('class').substring(4);
    tmp = parseInt(page_index);
    $('#book').turn('page', tmp);
    close_overlay();

    // cancel event bubbling
    cancelBubbleEvent(e);
})
```

Comment: sorry it is not working , when i drag on photo , it still trigger the click event

Comment: may be you should make a demo on JSFiddle.net

Comment: thanks, I used the similar idea and it works