# Prevent default behavior drag & drop image html in CSS but keep click event?

Tags: javascript, html, css, events

I need to disable the default drag & drop (and selection) on my  HTML.

I try in first time: `user-select: none; pointer-events: none;` in CSS.
It's works, but my click event javascript are disabled too... (and I need it)

so, is there a better solution that replace `pointer-events: none;` by

```
$document.on("dragstart", 'img', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

Can we do it in CSS only?

thx.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing click event with jQuery drag and drop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771627/preventing-click-event-with-jquery-drag-and-drop)

Comment: not realy... It's not drag & drop of jQuery here

Comment: @ivy_lynx can you delete "duplicate" tag plz, it's not the same problem. thx.