# Separating click from draggable functionality in JQuery

Tags: jquery, click, draggable, drag

Is there a way to separate a **click** events functionality from a **drag** events functionality if they are **both attached to the same object**?

I am adding a class on click. My goal for my application is that when a user has 'clicked' and item, that it's draggable functionality is disabled.

Conversely, if a user drags an item, the click should not fire off.

Is this possible?

Here's my fiddle with the code below included...

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doqpbuvy/)

html:

```
<div class="buttonBox"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
var bool = false;
var buttonBox = $(".buttonBox");

buttonBox.off("click");
buttonBox.on("click", function (event, ui) {
    console.log("class Added");
    $bool = true;
    var self = $(this);
    self.addClass("selectedBox");
});

buttonBox.draggable({
    distance: 40,
    disabled: bool,
    revert: "invalid",
    revertDuration: 400,
    refreshPositions: true,

});
```

Comment: you can try the .on() and .off() http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771627/preventing-click-event-with-jquery-drag-and-drop

Comment: In your posted code `buttonBox.off("click");` as no meaning

Comment: we're looking at a sample from a much larger application. I had read that you should pair a preceding .off() with your .on() so that your previous click events are removed before adding a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `start` event of draggable element to set your logic:

```
buttonBox.on("click", function (event, ui) {
    if($(this).hasClass('dragging')) {
        $(this).removeClass('dragging');
        return;
    }
    console.log("class Added");
    $bool = true;
    var self = $(this);
    self.addClass("selectedBox");
});

buttonBox.draggable({
    start: function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('selectedBox')) return false;
        $(this).addClass('dragging');
    },
    distance: 40,
    disabled: bool,
    revert: "invalid",
    revertDuration: 400,
    refreshPositions: true,

});
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: so I can probably just get rid of the bool variable?

Comment: @DanBeaulieu Ya it isn't used here

Answer (score 1):

You can wait for a short while at the start of click event, and fire the click event function only if that element is not being dragged by then.

```
buttonBox.on("click", function (event, ui) {
    setTimeout(function (ev, ui) {
        if($(ev.target).hasClass("ui-draggable-dragging"))
            return;
        console.log("class Added");
        $(ev.target).addClass("selectedBox");
    }, 50, event, ui);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/doqpbuvy/3/

Comment: this is a pretty nice solution as well. I'll look into both of these and see how they act in my project. Either way, I'll vote you up for taking the time to solve this. Thanks Ozan.