# nested clickable div with bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap MODAL plugin (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) with nested div. When click the inside div, I want to show the EDIT form, when click the container div, I want to show the ADD NEW form. Please see the code below.

```
<div id="container" style="width:300px;height:300px;border-style:double;cursor:pointer;" data-target="#add" data-toggle="modal">
    <div id="inside" data-target="#edit" data-toggle="modal" style="width:180px; height: 180px; background-color: Aqua; cursor: pointer;">
        click here to edit
    </div>
    click outside to add
</div>

<!-- Modal for edit -->
<div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">EDIT</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        (form for edit)
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">UPDATE</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal for add -->
<div class="modal fade" id="add" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">ADD NEW</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        (form for add new)
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">ADD</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, when click the inside div, both edit form and add new form will popup. If add `onclick="event.stopPropagation();"` in the inside div, it will stop the both two forms being popped up.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I have came up a solution

```
    $("#inside").click(function(){
        $("#inside").parent().addClass("no_click");
    });

    $("#container").click(function(event){
        if($(this).hasClass("no_click")){
            $(this).attr("data-toggle","");
            $(this).removeClass("no_click");
            return;
        }
        else{
            $(this).attr("data-toggle","modal");
        }
    });
```

The idea is come from this post [Preventing click event with jQuery drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771627/preventing-click-event-with-jquery-drag-and-drop). The problem in that post and my problem are both about one action trigger two events.

Comment: Actually there is a easier solution, instead of activate modal via HTML attribute, modal can also being activated by JavaScript (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage). And then the `onclick="event.stopPropagation();"` should works fine.