# Html click element vs selecting the content

Tags: html, onclick

Is there any way to differentiate between clicking a div element and selecting its content,

What I am looking for is to trigger click action only if the div was clicked
but not when its contents were selected

```
<div onClick="funA">
    Allow content to be copied if selected, else perform funA when clicked
</div>
```

Current onClick behavior triggers when I try to select the content and copy it, as soon as i unpress the click, But I want to not trigger funA or detect its selected and control it somehow.
I hope the question is clear enough, else I will add more specifics to the quesiton.

Comment: can you create a false click event on the content? this way nothing should happen inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see the difference this way :

```
<div id='click'>
    Allow content to be copied if selected, else perform funA when clicked
</div>
$('#click').click(function() {
    var sel = getSelection().toString();
    if(!sel){
        alert("clicked");
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Refering to [Preventing click event with jQuery drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771627/preventing-click-event-with-jquery-drag-and-drop[1]) using `$("#element").click(function(mouseEvent){ // click event });` will not execute when the mouse is dragged and dropped.

```
$("#funA").click(function(mouseEvent){  });

<div id="funA">
    Allow content to be copied if selected, else perform funA when clicked
</div>
```